# Двойная Windows 10, Потеря данных

Tags: linux, windows, файлы, ос, восстановление

Потребовалось установить вторую систему Windows 10 к уже имеющейся паре Windows 10 и Ubuntu.

Новая система ставилась на другой виртуальный диск, но теперь старая загрузка Win10 невозможна - ее дисковое пространство распознается как файловое.

Есть ли возможность вернуть старую систему, оставив ее в паре с Ubuntu? Сейчас через меню GRUB и BootMenu опция загрузки Windows загружает только новую версию без возможности выбора.

Comment: Виртуальный диск? Это как?

Comment: *дисковое пространство распознается как файловое* - поясните эту фразу